# Unable to locate modules/c folder while debugging LWC in browser

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, debug

So I've been working on several LWCs for SF community and suddenly the modules/c folder in browser's DevTools (both Firefox & Chrome) which contained all the custom components present on page dissapeared (**Note:** I'm working in sandbox). What I already tried:

- toggling Lightning debug mode for current user;
- toggling Lightning Web security in Session setting;
- clearing browser cache;
- changing component's API version

but I didn't succeed with any of them.

The only way to debug scripts live for me now is to explicitly put **debugger** statement as a breakpoint where needed.
Strangely, 2 weeks or so ago everything was fine, and even another Sandbox org from a different project doesn't have this issue.
Has anyone encountered the same issue before?[image: Here's how my Sources tab in DevTools lool like]

Comment: Hi, did you try to search the files by name?

Comment: Hi @RahulGawale, yep, I did, with no result.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you have to follow the steps in the salesforce guide

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/es/content/learn/modules/lwc-troubleshooting/get-ready-to-troubleshoot

There are 3 steps to follow:

1.

From Setup enter Debug Mode in the Quick Find box, and then select Debug Mode.
Check the box next to your user.
Click Enable.

[image]

2.
From Setup enter Session in the Quick Find box, and then select Session Settings.
Under Lightning Web Security, uncheck the box for Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components.
Click Save.

[image]

3 Perform an Empty Cache and Hard Reset

[image]